# Weird array behavior in Javascript / React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm new in ReactNative / Javascript. One weird thing that I notice is that if I have an array from parameter (ex: `[1, 0, 1, -1]`) and assign it to another variable and `console.log` it, I will get like an infinite array content.

```
myFunc = (array) => {
  console.log("ARRAY:");
  console.log(array);
  var result = array;
  console.log("RESULT:");
  console.log(result);
}
```

Resulting console log in iOS:

```
ARRAY:
[ 1, 0, 1, -1 ]
RESULT:
[ 1,
  0,
  1,
  -1,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ... 100 more rows
  ,
  [] ]
```

Why is this happening? And how to correctly assigning array contents from one variable to another?

Note that this only happens if the data is gotten from parameter. If I casually have `var array = [1, 0, 1, -1]` and assign it to another variable, there's no problem with that.

Comment: According to immutability, create a new object instead of reassign one: `const result = [...array]`

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] that illustrates the issue.

Comment: [mcve] please. ... My assumption based on the very little information: The array gets mutated elsewhere `array[200] = []`, and you missinterpret the consoles output ...

Comment: @JonasWilms it was the first code to execute after the function. The function was created specifically to try to reproduce this issue in minimal code.

Comment: The code as shown does not produce the log output.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L3dm2sv9/1/) but the result is as expected.

Without more information to do debugging and investigating. I think the biggest culprit might be the way OP copy the array.

By doing

```
var result = array;
```

If `array` value somehow changed, all changes will be reflected in `result` as well. ([example here](https://jsfiddle.net/L3dm2sv9/2/))

You can try to use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
var result = array.slice();
```

This answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486130/4424892) explain a lot about why `slice()` prevents problem above.

Comment: I was trying to answer the question "And how to correctly assigning array contents from one variable to another?".

Comment: Oh hey, wait, this actually gave me correct [1, 0, 1, -1] data! Why is that??

Comment: @Zendy If this is the correct answer, please explain why, because just right now, this looks like black magic!

Comment: I tried with some other array assignments, even array within array assignments, and it still works. But reading the slice() information, it returns "shallow copy" of the original. I don't know whether it works by removing those extra nil elements if I don't supply any parameters.

Comment: @ChenLiYong I updated the answer with some investigation result. See if that was your problem.

Comment: @sjahan thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer. If there is more room for improvement, Please let me know.